# How to create a Kivy file (.kv)

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

So I am working off of this tutorial: https://youtu.be/j9PqNe3J_Cc?t=1m55s

At the time stamp in that link (1:55) the guy goes over to another file he created. This file is a .kv file. When I try to create a new file, there are multiple options, but no kivy file type option. Should I just create a text file, or is there something I am missing?

For the record, I am using PyCharm, just like the guy in the video (also I'm using Mac)

Lastly, the guy's first file is called kivytut.py. Is that simply what he chose to name it, or are there generally accepted names for kivy files that people usually use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

## kv file

In PyCharm, click on `File > New > File` or `right mouse click New > File` and enter ***customwidget.kv*** as filename.

## Python file

You can name the file as *kivytut.py*. But if it is the ***main entry point*** to your Kivy App, then name it as *main.py* because Buildozer will be looking for a file with the name ***main.py***

## References » Programming Guide

Below are some of the titles. Please check out all the titles under Programming Guide.

[Kivy Basics](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/basic.html)

[Kv language](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html)

[Events and Properties](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/events.html)

Comment: great thanks! Is there any Kivy documentation that you would recommend? I am very comfortable in python, but am just learning about Kivy. I have looked at their documentation on their website, but it seems to assume that the reader already knows some info about Kivy. Are you aware of any online documentation that teaches people about Kivy from Square 1, with no previous knowledge?

Comment: Please refer to updated post for recommended Kivy documentations.

Comment: by that do you mean I should make a new post with this question?

Comment: In my updated post, I have added links to recommended Kivy documentation in response to your question, "Are you aware of any online documentation that teaches people about Kivy from Square 1?"

Answer (score 0):

All you are going to do is make it a text file 
Making it a python file will give lots of redlines
making your code look bad
Just make it a text file.